# Angular JS : How to stop sum of complex filed values crossing a limit?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of objects, in which each object has a percentage value. The user can enter any value. how can I limit the sum of percentage values to 100? For Eg:

> [ {"name":"Pradeesh","contribution":4534,"percentage":40},
>   {"name":"Kumar","contribution":3425,"percentage":30},
>   {"name":"Rajesh","contribution":1234,"percentage":20},
>   {"name":"Romeo","contribution":3434,"percentage":10}]

In this case, if anyone tries to change the value of percentage for any user, it should throw an error saying the total is more than 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your array of object is `myObject`, you can add a watcher over that object and check total percentage exceeds 100

```
$scope.$watch(function(){return myObject;},function (newValue,oldValue) {
    var totalPercentage = 0;
    newValue.forEach(function(value){
        totalPercentage += value.percentage;
    });
    if(totalPercentage > 100){
        myObject = oldValue;
        throw "Total Percentage Exceeds 100"; 
    }
},true);
```

Comment: I thought of this. But I wanted to change the value of percentage so that the total remains 100. Won't it create an infinite loop?

Comment: @PradeeshKumar it won't create an infinite loop unless you have an object that already exceeds 100.  To avoid an infinite loop better you first initialize `myObject = {}` first